# Imagem dentro de uma div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Galera seguinte, tenho um teste aqui e ele carrega algumas imagens no final e em algumas div, porem eu não consigo colocar ele pra carregar uma imagem na penultima div, tentei assim

```
var img = $('#oitavo1').val();
$('#pictures').attr('src', img);
```

e não funcionou, segue o código:

```
var testCounter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var sensorValor = '';
    var testEnabled = false;
    var roundedValue = 0;
    var contaBotao = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
      sensorValor = $('#counter').text();
    }), 100;

    $(".botaonibus").click(function(e){
      $('#contador').show();
      $('.meubotao').hide();
      $('.ingles').hide();

      var len = $('.testes1 div').length;

      // //Se for a primeira vez ele é 0 então não entrará, mas na segunda vez 
      //  ele entra no if e pega a div anterior "testCounter-1"
      if (len > testCounter){
        if(contaBotao > 0){
            $('.testes1 div').eq(testCounter-1).hide();
            $('#contador').show();
        }
        contaBotao++;
        $('.testes1 div').eq(testCounter).show();
        testCounter++;
        if (len == testCounter){
          $('.botaonibus').hide(); //ultima etapa ja chegou
          $('.goback').show();
          $('#contador').hide();
          $('#table').show();
          $('#nuts').show();
        } else {
          $('.botaonibus').html('Próxima Etapa');
          $('.botaonibus').addClass('proxEtapa1');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

o css da imagem

```
  #pictures {
  width: 1216px;
  height: 323px;
  background-image: url('../images/pictures.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 400px;
  display:none;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TESTE DO FREIO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/botao.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/conteudo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/botaonibus.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/conteudobus.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ingles.css">

  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
    html{
      overflow-y:hidden;
      overflow-x:hidden;
    -->
      }
  </style>

  </head>

<body>

<a class="goback" href="index.html">Finalizar Teste</a>  

<div id="tabela"></div>

<div id="contador"></div>

<div id="pictures"></div>

<div id="table"></div>

<div id="nuts"></div>

<label id="counter">0</label>

<div id="teste"></div>

<a class="botaonibus">Teste Ônibus</a>
  <div class=testes1>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="primeiro1">Instruções: Realizar uma medição de pressão dos freios.<p>1. Cheque a especificação de acordo com o SCIM 62005.</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="segundo2">2. As partes estão corretas montadas de acordo com o ajuste, função e término.<p><span class="vermelho">Preparação para medição de pressão dos freios (4x2, 6x2)</p></span><p><b>Equipamento Necessário:</b> 6 manometros <span class="vermelho">(15 bar)</span>.</p><p>Conectar manometro no circuito de manobra de freio de estacionamento do eixo traseiro.</p><p>A pressão no sistema deve ser igual a pressão da direção quando testado. Pressão de trabalho deve ser no mino <span class="vermelho">8,0 bar</span> no circuito de suprimento(circuito do motor)</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="terceiro3">3.1. <b>Cheque do vazamento de ar</b><p>O freio de estacionamento deve estar na posição de direção.</p><p>A pressão deve cair para o máximo <span class="vermelho">0,5 bar</span> nos manometros quando o serviço de freio está engatado (pedal pressionado para baixo) por 30 minutos.</p><p>Localize qualquer vazamento de ar.</p><p><b>Solte o tubo/mangueira C</b></p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="quarto4">3.2. <b>Teste para checar a válvula do circuito de freio de estacionamento.</b><p>A pressão deve ser maior que <span class="vermelho">6 bar</span> no circuito de freio de estacionamento.</p><p>Esvazie o tanque do freio de estacionamento. Cheque se não tem queda de presão notável no manômetro de manobra do circuito freio de estacionamento.</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="quinto5">3.3. <b>Cheque o freio de estacionamento/Válvula de bloqueio</b><p>Em ônibus com válvula de bloqueio, ela deve estar aberto.</p><p>O freio de serviço não pode estar engatado. A alavanca do freio de estacionamento deve estar na posição de direção.</p><p>Leia a pressão no freio do circuito de estacionamento. A pressão deve estar no minimo <span class="vermelho">6,5 bar</span> no manometro do circuito do freio de estacionamento. Coloque a alavanca na posição de estacionamento, o chassis com válvula de bloqueio deve estar ativado. Leia a pressão no manometro do circuito de pressão do freio de estacionamento. A pressão deve estar em 0 bar.</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="sexto6">3.4. <b>Cheque se a pressão e prioridades está fechando no APS</b><p>Tenha certeza que tem pressão no circuito do motor. Simular vazamento por E.G. vazio do tanque de ar por ACC.</p><p>Cheque se todos os circuitos estão fechados antes da pressão no ACC cair entre <span class="vermelho">4,5 bar</span> abaixo.</p><p>Esvazie todo o sistema de freio, esvaziando todos os tanques de ar</p><p>Cheque se o circuito de freio do tanque está conectado corretamente</p><p>Feche os tanques de ar</p><p>Ligue o motor e mantanha funcionando até 1000 rpm</p><p>O sistem de freio será abastecido.</p><p>Cheque se o circuito do freio de estacionamento não está abastecido antes da soma de pressão nos circuitos dianteiros e traseiros estejam juntos seja <span class="vermelho">>7,2 bar</span>.<p>Escute e cheque se o regulador solta a pressão pelo compressor.</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="setimo7">3.5. <b>Cheque de instrumentos</b><p>Ligue o motor e carregue o sistema de ar para <span class="vermelho">>9 bar</span>.</p><p>* Para o motor e disconecte o reservátorio de ar.</p><p>* Ligue a inginição.</p><p>Cheque a pressão dos freios no manômetro do ICL mostra a mesma pressão do circuito traserio e dianteiro.</p><p>Trave a pressão para baixo em aproximadamente <span class="vermelho">5 bar</span> com o pedal de freio, então o "aviso de pressão baixa" deve avisar.</p><p>Cheque se o circuito frontal/traseiro não está misturados no manômetro de pressão do freio.<p>*Drene a pressão do tanque de ar pelo circuito frontal apenas para checar se a pressão mostrada no manômetro do circuito dianteiro diminui.</p><p>Drene a pressão do tanque de ar pelo cicuito traseiro apenas para checar se a pressão mostrada no manômetro do circuito traseiro diminui.</p><p>O manômetro do circuito dianteiro não deve se mover.</p></div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="oitavo8">3.6. <b>Secador de ar</b><p>O dreno de secador de ar quando o compressor solta a pressão.</p><p>O cheque é realizado por uma mão desviada contra o silenciador de secadores de ar e veja se liberou o ar.</p> </div>
  <div align="center" class='conteudo' id="oitavo18">4.1. <b>Cheque do torque</b><p>Porcas no bloco do circuito do APS</p><p>Veja a figura:</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/scriptbus.js"></script>
```

Comment: Se a imagem foi carregada por `background-image` em css então a troca por jquery devia ser da mesma maneira `$('#pictures').css('background-image', img);`. Falta no entanto ver ainda o html.

Comment: o HTML amigo está assim

Comment: tentei sua opção, porém não funcionou

Comment: O valor que entra no css tem de estar dentro de `url()` logo ou o seu `img` tem isso ou terá que fazer algo como `$('#pictures').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')' );` . Aconselho também a confirmar se tem o caminho correto em `img`